# SQL query gives too many results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a PostgreSQL query for the problem:

How many products have been bought in 2011? (Bought in 2011 means that the orderdescription is 'Completed' in 2011).
[image: diagram]

So far I've got this query:

```
    SELECT
      COUNT(product.id)
    FROM
      product
    JOIN orderitem ON 
      productid = product.id
    JOIN "order" ON 
      "order".id = orderitem.orderid AND
      EXTRACT(year FROM orderplaced) = 2011
    JOIN orderstatus ON 
      orderstatus.orderid = "order".id
    JOIN orderstatusdescription ON 
      orderstatusdescription.id = orderstatusdescriptionid AND
      orderstatusdescription.description = 'Completed';
```

But this results in 231410 products while the database only contains 1000. Using `DISTINCT(product.id)` logically results in a count of 1000.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: If there is only 1 orderstatus 'completed', I'd say it's about right that that many separate product ids are in orders. If you'd `SUM(amount)` you get the total number of items sold, it you `COUNT(DISTINCT product.id)` you get the number of unique products sold?

Comment: Surely you should be joining on order.id = orderitem.id and not orderid?

Comment: It's not the cause of your problem but you should move `EXTRACT(year FROM orderplaced) = 2011` and `orderstatusdescription.description = 'Completed'` to WHERE clause since it's not part of the join logic.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, but none of them worked out.

Comment: @JorenHammudoglu My suggestion would be to debug this by removing each table/join and slowly add them back in to determine what is causing the increase.

Comment: Try a COUNT(orderitems.productid) ?

Comment: If you are trying to find the number of different products bought, and each product can appear in several orders, you WILL have to use `DISTINCT` in one way or another.

Comment: @Oli Still the same result...

Comment: `... the database only contains 1000` If widget was ordered 1000 times on 1000 different orders, should it be counted once or a thousand times?  Do you want count distinct or count?

Answer (score 2):

Slightly modified query from Andres Olarte:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(orderitem.productid)
FROM
  orderitem
JOIN "order" ON 
  "order".id = orderitem.orderid
JOIN orderstatus ON 
  orderstatus.orderid = "order".id
JOIN orderstatusdescription ON 
  orderstatusdescription.id = orderstatusdescriptionid 
WHERE 
  EXTRACT(year FROM orderplaced) = 2011
AND  orderstatusdescription.description = 'Completed';
```

Comment: @Joren What do you expect the query to return?

Comment: I expect an integer in the range 0 .. 1000

Comment: @Joren which according to your question is what you get when you do `COUNT(DISTINCT product.id)` ...

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(product.id)
FROM
  product
JOIN orderitem ON 
  productid = product.id
JOIN "order" ON 
  "order".id = orderitem.orderid
JOIN orderstatus ON 
  orderstatus.orderid = "order".id
JOIN orderstatusdescription ON 
  orderstatusdescription.id = orderstatusdescriptionid 
WHERE 
  EXTRACT(year FROM orderplaced) = 2011
AND  orderstatusdescription.description = 'Completed';
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but still the excact same result.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a larger number because you have multiple records being match by one or more of your join conditions.

For example, when you join the `product` table to `orderitem` you probably have more than one `orderitem` record that gets matched. So you get that `product.id` in your result set more than once.

Try `COUNT(distinct product.id)` -- that should give you the count of distinct products that were purchased.

Answer (score 1):

This will tell you which products were bought in 2011 (untested -- not at computer with PG):

```
     select distinct OI.productid, P.description
     from orderitem OI inner join products P on OI.productid=P.id
     inner join
     (   
     select order.id as orderid from order
     inner join orderstatusdescription OSD
     on order.orderstatusdescriptionid = OSD.id and OSD.description = 'COMPLETED'
     where extract(year from order.orderplaced)=2011  
     ) as Orders2011
     on Orders2011.orderid = OI.orderid
```